# mysql data existence code not working

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to check a data existence from mysql table but following script not working. bellow my codes are provided please find out where is my mistake there.

```
<?php
//including the database files
include("../inc/settings.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT easy123 FROM users WHERE email=$email", $conn);

  if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
  {
      echo "Username already exists";
  }

  else
  {
    echo "this username not used";
  }

?>
```

The error i am getting is-

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\Easy123\master\login.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\Easy123\master\login.php on line 10
>   this username not used

Comment: Check your database connection in `settings.php` file . `$conn` is undefine in your code

Comment: An email address would typically be a string, and string literals need to be quoted in SQL

Comment: Although you should move into the 21st century, and start using prepared statements/bind variables with MySQLi or PDO, especially as the newest version of PHP is dropping the MySQL extension completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure your database connection is correctly set up. The error you're getting clearly says that your `$conn` variable isn't a valid resource.

Also, **use prepared statements and parameterized queries**. Do not use PHP variables within your query string, it's not secure at all. Use instead PDO or MySQLi

1. Using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

   ```php
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT easy123 FROM users WHERE email = :email');

   $stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));

   foreach ($stmt as $row) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```
2. Using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

   ```php
   $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT easy123 FROM users WHERE email = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

   $stmt->execute();

   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your **$query** seems to be wrong. Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT easy123 FROM users WHERE email='$email'", $conn);
```

Make sure **$conn** is properly defined aswell.